# How to turn off the blue barrier below the Nali church in Bluff Eversmoking

Tags: unreal-gold

I found a way to turn off the blue barrier below the Nali church in *Bluff Eversmoking* by walking on an edge (see screenshot below). I wonder if there is not another more casual way which doesn't expect the player to climb along a small path on the wall.

[image]

It is often possible to shorten the way from A to B in Unreal by rocket jumping and sometimes by walking on edges. Most edge walks reward the player with items but this time it doesn't feel right to me. I don't want to *cut corners* on this playthrough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though that *is* the correct way forward. I think that's the way I did it back in the day, and [guides seem to suggest the same thing:](https://www.oldunreal.com/walkthrough/u1-24-p.html)

> "You need to get past these beams to deactivate them... if you look, you will see that a white balcony-level beam that separates the offshoot from the main room continues right along to the balcony and protrudes slightly from the wall at this end. So, creep along this raised beam and jump off, over the electric field, into the offshoot area."

It's hard for me to remember exactly *which* barrier this is in the level, but some of the barriers in "Bluff Eversmoking" can be disabled by activating the Transformers in some of the other rooms.

[Here's](http://www.snipersparadise.net/walkthroughs.html) some more info about similar barriers: (Spoliers!)

> "ISV-Kran Deck 1: Warning 85,000 volt electrical field barrier in place at Science Research Lab. Power distribution from three transformer control rooms active." Well, you just disabled the first, so exit the room and walk down the hall to your right until you find transformer room 3. Walk inside. From here, exit the room and turn left. Along the way, you'll pass a door on your left blocked by blue energy bars. Continue past it until you find transformer room 2. Touch the final button here and return to the door previously blocked by blue energy bars. It will now be open."